# Unable to retrieve aggregationValue from below mentioned xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<ContentItem xmlns="http://endeca.com/schema/content/2008" type="GenericMarketingContent">
      <TemplateId>OneRecordBanner</TemplateId>
      <Name>One Record Banner</Name>
      <Property name="title">
        <String>Recommended</String>
      </Property>
      <Property name="image">
        <String>green.gif</String>
      </Property>
      <Property name="alt_text">
        <String>Image Alt text</String>
      </Property>
      <Property name="record_list">
        <RecordSelection xmlns="http://endeca.com/schema/content/xtags/2010">
          <RecordList>
            <Record key="pp500231036301401000091" aggregationKey="grp_id">
              <aggregationValue>pp5002310363</aggregationValue>
              <label>Deer Stags Manager Mens Slip On Shoes</label>
            </Record>
          </RecordList>
          <recordLimit>1</recordLimit>
        </RecordSelection>
      </Property>
</ContentItem>
```

```
/ContentItem/Property[@name='record_list']/RecordSelection/RecordList/Record/aggregationValue/text()
```

is not fetching value. I am able to get all other values for other property tags but not this one.Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Given the `xmlns` declarations, I'm surprised _any_ XPaths using unprefixed element names are returning results at all.  What tool, language and/or XPath library are you using here?

Comment: @IanRoberts:I did use the namespace declaration as mentioned in the below comment by Ifurini.My bad ,I did not mention that in the question . I am not using any special tool to answer your question :)

Comment: Somehow I overlooked the "xslt" tag, since you didn't show any XSLT code in the question (only XPath expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `RecordSelection` and its descendants are in a different namespace than the rest of the XML document.

If you are using xslt 2.0, you can use this xpath:

```
/ContentItem/Property[@name='record_list']/*:RecordSelection/*:RecordList/*:Record/*:aggregationValue
```

A (probably cleaner) solution would be declaring the namespaces using a prefix, so that you can use this xpath:

```
/w1:ContentItem/w1:Property[@name='record_list']/w2:RecordSelection/w2:RecordList/w2:Record/w2:aggregationValue
```

with`w1` being a prefix for `http://endeca.com/schema/content/2008` and `w2` for `http://endeca.com/schema/content/xtags/2010`

(Note that you don't need the final `/text()`)

Comment: for the same xml if there are more record tags I am usiing for each to iterate but getting the first record's aggregation value for both the records.

<xsl:for-each select="/widget:ContentItem/widget:Property[@name='record_list']/temp:RecordSelection/temp:RecordList/temp:Record">
<String>
<xsl:value-of select="//widget:Property[@name='record_list']/temp:RecordSelection/temp:RecordList/temp:Record/temp:aggregationValue"/>
</String>
</xsl:for-each>

where am i going wrong ? confused

Comment: @uttejreddy: inside your `for-each` the context node is a `temp:Record `element, so you simply have to use `<xsl:value-of select="temp:aggregationValue"/>` (your XPath starting with `//` selects the `temp:aggregationValue` element **anywhere in the document**, and with xslt 1.0 the value of the first one is returned)

Comment: @uttejreddy: another option is looping directly over the `temp:aggregationValue` elements: 
`<xsl:for-each select="//widget:ContentItem/widget:Property[@name='record_list']/temp:RecordSelection/temp:RecordList/temp:Record/temp:aggregationValue">
<String>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</String>
</xsl:for-each>`

Answer (score 1):

RecordSelection and its children are in a different namespace, and you're not accounting for that.

The ugly hack version of fixing this would involve a bunch of local-name calls.  The elegant version would be to define the namespace in your XSLT.